# Adding Service Reference is not showing all my Interfaces

Tags: c#, wcf

When I add a new service reference in my project, I can see that both my interfaces are showing up as its supposed to:

[image]

However in my code, I can only see the function for the first service on not the second service. I can see: 
`AdvantekServiceClient() but not WellServiceClient()`. It seems as if the WellServiceClient code is not being generated.

My Service class:
[image]

My Config file:
[image]

The Reference.cs file in the Service References folder is not creating any other classes but the IAdvantekService.

Comment: Does the AdvantekServiceClient implement both interfaces?

Comment: @JohnKoerner Yes it does.

Comment: Can you provide the interface definitions?

Comment: @vesuvious I added some additional information.

Comment: Hmm...so far everything looks okay to me. How about the interface classes themselves? My only thought is that datacontracts are not setup properly on IWellService or that it is private or something.

Comment: Well, your **client code** will connect to exactly **one** service endpoint - and that **one** endpoint implements **one contract** only - so what exactly is your expectation? You get those methods that are defined in the **endpoint's contract** that you connect to ...

Comment: @marc_s Yes, however when using this method, it will show that I have the Data service AdvantekService but should also create multiple clients for the different interfaces. If I made another interface called ILogService and added it, it should create LogServiceClient on the other side.